# How I change the name of a VoiceChannel with the name but got by me in a variable? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
I need to find a way to change the name of a VoiceChannel but with only one command, that is, if I put only one command, for example "!open" the name of the channel changes to open.
```

```
@bot.command()
async def abierto(ctx):
    nome = "Cerrado"
    for i in ctx.guild.channels:
        if i.name == nome:
            await nome.edit(name = "Abierto")
        else:
            await ctx.send("El código no funcionó, te vas a dormir.")
```

I hope that with a single command you can change the name of a channel, giving it in advance in a variable the ID or name of the channel.

Comment: wait u need to write !anyname to change ALL vc to "anyname"

Comment: Only one VC I want to change. 
For example, I write !open, so the channel will have to change to open.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using arguments

```
@bot.command()
async def change(ctx, name: str, newname: str):
    nome = name
    for i in ctx.guild.channels:
        if i.name == nome:
            await nome.edit(name = newname")
        else:
            await ctx.send("El código no funcionó, te vas a dormir.")
```

Let me break this down for you; say your prefix is `!`. With this command, you are able to add arguments while calling the command. For example, `!change <channel name> <new name>`
If you had a channel called `Voice` that you want to change to `Music`, `!change Voice Music`

Another way of doing it; wait for another response:

```
@client.command()
async def change(ctx):
  await ctx.send('Send channel name and new channel name separated by a comma. \nEx. Voice, Music')
  response = await client.wait_for("message", timeout=60)
  response = response.content.split(", ")
  channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, name=response[0])
  await channel.edit(name=response[1])
```

Comment: I get it, actually I tried it with arguments, but the problem is that if the channel has a name with spaces then I won't be able to refer to it, for example:
!change <How are you?> <Fine, thanks>
This code would give an error because it doesn't know how to capture the spaces in each name.
One more thing, is there a way to be able to do it without arguments? For example, instead of passing it the arguments that it already has in a variable, then all I would have to do is run the command and the channel would change its name to the one I gave it in a variable. Thanks for the help. Cheers!

Comment: No channel has a name with spaces, you can't create a channel with spaces only with letters, numbers, unicode, hyphens and underscores

Comment: I've edited my response anyway